# RegEx to clean all ' chars

Tags: python, regex

I have a RSS feed parser, and I'm using Regex to clean up the tags. I am having trouble with reg4 to clean all ' chars, and I want to know what I can do with reg4?:

```
reg1 = re.compile(r'<br />') #Regex to replace <br /> with \n (see reg1.sub)
reg2 = re.compile(r'(<!--.*?-->|<[^>]*>)') #Regex to clean all html tags (anything with <something>)
reg3 = re.compile(r'&nbsp') #Regex to clean all &nbsp 
reg4 = re.compile(r'') #Regex to clean all ' chars (this is causing me issues for some reason)

def parseFeeds( str ):
 d = feedparser.parse(str)
 print "There are", len(d['items']), "items in", str
 FILE_INPUT = open("outputNewsFeed.txt","w")
 for item in d['items']:
  first_filter = reg1.sub('\n', item.description)
  second_filter = reg2.sub('', first_filter)
  third_filter = reg3.sub(' ', second_filter)
  item_description = reg4.sub('', third_filter)
  try:
   FILE_INPUT.write(item_description)
  except IOError:
   print "Error: can\'t find file or read data"
 FILE_INPUT.close
```

Here is my current sample output:

```
There are 25 items in http://www.reddit.com/r/python/.rss

[link] [12 comments]submitted by  rasbt  
[link] [comment]submitted by  iamsidd2k7  
[link] [comment]submitted by  josephturnip2  
[link] [28 comments]submitted by  Maslo59  
[link] [1 comment]The Source code isn't wonderful (I'm only a hobbyist, no were near a pro) but I use this whenever I'm at my desktop, and need to make some kind of decision or choose between two things, its sort of based off my unsure nature, lol.
```

Comment: A regular expression to clean up the tags? Using BeautifulSoup would be easier and more durable.

Comment: `r''` is just an empty string.

Comment: I have used BeautifulSoup and xml.etree, but here I'm using regex for exercise sake.

Comment: Yes, reg4 = re.compile(r'') is empty, I'm struggling with what to insert to remove the ' chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to remove the single quote, you can escape it like so:

```
reg4 = re.compile(r'\'')
```

Or if you don't mind changing the way you write strings, you could use:

```
reg4 = re.compile(r"'")
```